# Making new classes with math operators

Tags: vb.net, class

I'm trying to make new classes and am supposed to use the math operators +,_,*,/. As I'm new to vb.net and making classes I don't really understand why using the operators causes an Identifier expected error. Is it because they are reserved or something? How would I go about using the operators as a new class?

```
Public Class MathOp

Private + As String
Private - As String

End Class
```

Comment: To answer your question, yes, + and - are reserved operators in vb.net. If you want to create your own functionality for them, you'll need to overload them yourself.

Comment: There's info at [Operator Procedures (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh17yw4c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented, you'll need to implement your own functionality for the operators in the class if you want to use them. Here's an example:

```
Public Class MathOp

Private Readonly m_num As Double

Public Sub New(ByVal num As Double)
    m_num = num
End Sub

Public Readonly Property Num As Double
    Get
        Return m_num
    End Get
End Property

Public Shared Operator +(ByVal lhs As MathOp, ByVal rhs As MathOp)
As MathOp
Return New MathOp(lhs.m_num + rhs.m_num)
End Operator

End Class
```

Then you can use as such:

```
Dim m1, m2, m3 As MathOp
m1 = New MathOp(1)
m2 = New MathOp(2)
m3 = m1 + m2
```